# How to let download file keep running after Home button pressed on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I am developing an iPhone app.

It needs to download some files in the background and it will take several hours, so I want to let the user just press Home button to send it back and do other jobs.

Is it possible to let the download task keep running in the background after Home button was pressed? (iOS4/iOS5)

Comment: Apple are not going to like that when you get to the submission page, even if you do find a way around it. It will hammer the battery life, and potentially peoples connection if they are on 2G etc.

Could you explain *why* you want to do this, and an iOS dev on here might be able to suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only for 10 minutes:

See "task completion" in [iOS Multitasking Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)